# wikipedia has block tor exit nodes... anyway around this?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Not a fan of Wiki logging my IP just to edit something. Is there a way around this or should I look for another proxy. Any suggestions???

Comment: There is already a good quality question for this problem containing a solution (described directly on Wikipedia): [Editing Wikipedia on Tor without creating an account?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/5995/114)

Answer (score 1):

Tor is completely blocked on Wikipedia for new users, so you will need to use another proxy with Tor if you want to edit it. However, Wikipedia is able to whitelist individual users who have a genuine need. I have had success in the past by sending an email to a moderator and showing them what I would edit, asking them if they could either edit it on my behalf or whitelist my account.